# Dovecot IMAP (port 143) not working with SASL while Postfix (port 25) is

Tags: email, authentication, postfix, dovecot, sasl

I've got SASLAuthd working (via LDAP), and am also successfully able to telnet via port 25 with my LDAP credentials. Postfix is configured with Dovecot. All 3 services are running fine (Postfix, Dovecot, SASLAuthd)

I can also connect on port 143 however when I try to use "a login  " it only applies PAM auth (ie. LDAP and presumably SASL isn't being recognized for IMAP)

Not vomiting configs yet (on Request)

```
postconf -a
```

outputs:

```
cyrus
dovecot
```

In the **/var/log/mail.log** I see `Apr  9 01:36:22 localhost dovecot: auth-worker(18053): pam(user_x,127.0.0.1): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)`
.. Nothing in /var/log/mail.err

I have followed whatever docs I could get my hands. Additionally a history of what I have been through so far is here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194204/ubuntu-postfix-open-ldap-integration-no-sasl-authentication-mechanisms/194560#194560

Answer (score 1):

While I could not get around the SASL issue ... for other modules that do not support SASL; PAM is used.

I integrated PAM with LDAP (pam_ldap.so). If you have PAM also using LDAP successfully then you can avoid having to rely only on SASL.

Not the desirable solution but an effective and logical workaround.